# ASP.NET MVC + AngularJS + PiranhaCMS + Foundation for Apps routing issue

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angular-ui-router, zurb-foundation, piranha-cms

I have been working on this issue for longer than I'd like to admit. I have read everything I could find closely resembling my issue, and have come up empty handed.

The problem I am having is getting my views to show WITH _Layout.cshtml. When I fire up the site, the Index.cshtml view is being loaded, but without the layout page.

Here is _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"  ng-app="retail">
<head>
  <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  @UI.Head()
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/Css/style.css"/>
  @RenderSection("head", required: false)
</head>
<body>

<!-- This is the off-canvas menu that will slide in from the left !-->
<zf-offcanvas id="OffCanvasMainMenu" position="left">
  <div id="MainMenu">
    <div class="menuBlock">
      <span class="spacer"></span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</zf-offcanvas>

<div class="grid-frame vertical">
  <div id="Header" class="shrink collapse grid-content">
    <div class="dark title-bar">
                <span class="title center">
                    <img class="logo" src="logo.png">
                </span>
                <span class="left">
                    <button zf-toggle="OffCanvasMainMenu" id="MainMenuToggle">
                        <span>toggle menu</span>
                    </button>
                </span>
      <span class="right"><a id="c-button--slide-right" class="c-button dark"><i
        class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-block">
    <ui-view>
    </ui-view>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- This is the Shopping Cart that will slide over from the right !-->
<nav id="c-menu--slide-right" class="c-menu c-menu--slide-right">
  <button class="c-menu__close">Close Menu &rarr;</button>
</nav><!-- /c-menu slide-right -->

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="../../lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="../../lib/ui-bootstrap-custom/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/build/foundation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/build/templates.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/app/core/core.module.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/154af4e77a.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/app/home/HomeController.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/assets/menu.js"></script>

</body>

@RenderSection("script", required: false)
</html>
```

I am using UI Router with AngularJS to provide client-side, HTML5Mode routing. Here is my app.js:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('retail', [
    'retail.core'
  ])
    .config(config)
    .run(run);

  config.$inject = ["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider"];

  function config($stateProvider, $urlProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
      .state("home", {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "/Home/Index",
        controller: "HomeController",
        controllerAs: "home"
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: false,
      requireBase: false
    });

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
  }

  function run() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
  }

})();
```

Here is /Home/Index/cshtml:

```
@model Piranha.Models.PageModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div class="content">
  <div class="main">
    <h1>@Model.Page.Title</h1>
    @Model.Regions.Ad
  </div>
  <div>
    @Model.Regions.CampaignHeader
  </div>
  <div>
    @Model.Regions.CampaignProduct1
  </div>
  <div>
    @Model.Regions.CampaignProduct2
  </div>
  <div>
    @Model.Regions.CampaignProduct3
  </div>
  <div>
    @Model.Regions.CampaignProduct4
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : SinglePageController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = GetModel();

            return PartialView("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", model);
        }
}
```

If there is any further code that needs to be seen, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In /home/index.cshtml

You state that you want the Layout to be null. This literally says that you don't want a layout used with this file. If you have a _ViewStart.cshtml it most likely will be pointing to ~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml by default. If not you need to make

```
Layout = "<path>/<to>/_Layout"
```

In HomeController.cs, you are returning PartialView(...); which is primarially used for AJAX and for calling Sub-Views. It ignores the layout options if specified. You want to use

```
View(...);
```

Comment: The Layout is set to null in order to properly achieve a SPA. This is also why I am returning a PartialView from the controller. That partial view is supposed to be inserted, via Angular routing, between the `<ui-view></ui-view>` tags in _Layout.cshtml. Based on everything I have read, the _Layout.cshtml should still loaded as normal.

Comment: This answer is totally correct. Specifying Layout = null will make sure the Layout is never used. This has nothing to do with Piranha CMS but is standard MVC functionality. To create a SPA, make sure your initial route (home/index) returns a view with an empty body and is including the Layout. Then make sure that all other actions called from Angular sets Layout = null. This will give you the behavior you're looking for! Regards